# What lens is ideal for graduation and family pictures?

Tags: lens, portrait, lens-recommendation, group-photos

I am currently using a Tamron 17-50 f2.8 for graduation and family pictures, so that many people can fit into the frame, but I find this lens isn't sufficient enough — lack of sharpness around the edges. What is the ideal gear to shoot such pictures (outdoor & in a studio) and why so?

This is a sample: http://s4.postimg.org/ndiqa2hwt/Family2_final.jpg

Comment: What f-stop did you select in the sample photo?

Comment: I believe it was between f9 and f11 with shutter speed of 1/125

Comment: Related: [What is the advantage of a lens with a curved focal plane?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83070/15871)

Comment: [Why might focus fall off at the edges?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90759/15871)

Answer (score 1):

> i find this lens isnt sufficient enough, lack of sharpness around the edges.

I wonder has anyone ever complained to you about this ?  I ask because many people seem obsessed with sharpness and edges which, to the viewer, are utterly unimportant.

I think the problem is not the lens, but your mindset.

> I still wonder to this very day what is the ideal gear to shoot such pictures (outdoor & in a studio) and why so?

There is no such thing as "ideal gear".

There's an old saying : *What's the best lens for shot ?  The lens you have on your camera it's happening.".

It's what works for you and the subject and the viewer.  Not what's ideal in some abstract sense.

Again, if no one has complained about your photos, you probably have as close to ideal as you need.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, its true that no one actually complained to me about sharpness etc.. but I tend to compare my shots to related works and to my eyes I just can't get it as sharp as theirs.

Comment: I would assume with a photo of graduation you might wanna draw attention to your subject, which means that less sharpness at the edges is a feature, not a bug. People want to see the important bits, and that's usually faces of the people you're interested in. And a telephoto might be helpful for shots of people on stage at a distance.